# What does "len(A) - 1" mean?

Tags: python, syntax

From "Elements of Programming Interviews in Phyton", page 37, this little program reorders an array of integers so that the even numbers appear first.

```
def even_odd(A):
    next_even, next_odd = 0, len(A) - 1
    while next_even < next_odd:
        if A[next_even] % 2 == 0:
            next_even += 1
        else:
            A[next_even], A[next_odd] = A[next_odd], A[next_even]
            next_odd -= 1
```

My question: what does the "-1" in "len(A) - 1" do/mean?

Comment: it is the length of A minus 1

Comment: It subtracts `1` from the number returned by `len(A)`… But I'm sure you know that. What exactly don't you understand about that number?

Comment: its an method to find the [length](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) of the list.

Comment: @Siva we should say iterable, as `A` might be a string

Comment: Konstantin below gave the answer that I was looking for. I did not understand that len(A) - 1 is assigned to next_odd. These syntax shortcuts are normally not thaught in the textbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you assign values to variables:
`next_even` to **0** and `next_odd` to **len(A) - 1**:

```
next_even, next_odd = 0, len(A) - 1
```

Same as:

```
next_even = 0
next_odd = len(A) - 1  # len([1, 2, 3]) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks, Konstantin! Crystal-clear now.

Answer (score 5):

`len(A)-1` actually is the index of the last element in list `A`. As in python (and almost all programming languages), array indexes start from 0, so an array with n elements has index of `0, 1, 2, ..., n-1`.

Comment: @user The syntax `A[-1]` gives you the last ***value*** in the list. `len(A)-1` gives you the last ***index***.

Comment: @deceze True, and that makes this answer technically correct. Though I wonder what the question really is. I mean, another answer is that it's the length of the iterable minus 1, or the amount of elements in a list minus 1, but the question is: what is really the question.

Comment: @user770 ```A[-1]``` should be considered as a abbreviation of ```A[len(A)-1]``` which is implemented in python. In general, one should use length-1 as the index of last element, this works for almost all languages, including python!